# Game of Life Border- Checking for Live Cells

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

I am making Conway's Game of Life for a C++ class that I am taking and I can't seem to make it stay in range  on the borders. We are using an ancient class, so the explanation of it is below.

`<lvp\matrix.h>` - Allows for re-sizable 2-dimensional arrays

Usage -

declaration - `matrix<itemType> itemName(numRows, numColumns, fillValue)`

passing to functions - `(itemName)`

parameter in functions - either `(const matrix<itemType> &name)` or that without the `'const'` in front.

So here is a picture of the problem (vector is a class that matrix is based off of, it makes arrays and has methods that make it very easy to re-size).

http://imageshack.com/a/img835/2531/03gx.png

Just remember that I am a beginner programmer, so please be gentle with your criticisms :)

And thank you in advance.

So here is the code so far:

```
#include <lvp\matrix.h>
#include <iostream.h>

//--------------------------------------------------------------

void displayBoard(const matrix<char> &board)
{
    cout << "   1  2  3  4  5  6  7" << endl;
    for( int row=0; row<board.numrows(); row++)
    {
        cout << row+1 << " ";
        for( int col = 0; col < board.numcols(); col++)
            cout<<"["<<board[row][col]<<"]";
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------

void placeLiveCells(matrix<char> &board, matrix<char> &check)
{
    //Test function
    board[3][3]='X';
    board[3][4]='X';
    board[3][2]='X';
    check[3][3]='X';
    check[3][4]='X';
    check[3][2]='X';
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------



//--------------------------------------------------------------

void checkNeighbors(matrix<char> &board, int row, int col)
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        if(board[row][col+1]=='X')
            count++;
        if(board[row][col-1]=='X')
            count++;
        if(board[row+1][col+1]=='X')
            count++;
        if(board[row-1][col-1]=='X')
                count++;
        if(board[row+1][col-1]=='X')
            count++;
        if(board[row-1][col+1]=='X')
            count++;
        if(board[row+1][col]=='X')
            count++;
        if(board[row-1][col]=='X')
            count++;
        if(count<2)
            board[row][col]='O';
        if(count>3)
            board[row][col]='O';
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------

void findX(matrix<char> &board)
{
    int numspots=board.numrows()*board.numcols(), r=0, c;
    for(int j=0; j<numspots; j++)
    {
        if(board[r][c]=='X')
            checkNeighbors(board, r, c);  /*This is where I think the 
problem is, the code was working ok before I added this function*/
        if(c==6)
        {
            c=0;
            r++;
        }
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    int row=0, col=0;
    matrix<char> check(7, 7, 'O');
    matrix<char> board(7, 7, 'O');
    displayBoard(board);
    placeLiveCells(board, check);
    displayBoard(board);
    findX(board);
    checkNeighbors(board, row, col);

    return(0);
}
```

My next attempt on checkNeighbors includes checking for out-of-bound errors <0, which still doesn't work:

```
void checkNeighbors(matrix<char> &board, int row, int col)
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        if((row-1>=0) && (col-1>=0))
        {
            if(board[row][col+1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row][col-1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row+1][col+1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row-1][col-1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row+1][col-1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row-1][col+1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row+1][col]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row-1][col]=='X')
                count++;
            if(count<2)
                board[row][col]='O';
            if(count>3)
                board[row][col]='O';
        }
        else if((row-1<0) && (col-1>=0))
        {
            if(board[row][col+1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row][col-1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row+1][col+1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row][col-1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row+1][col-1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row][col+1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row+1][col]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row][col]=='X')
                count++;
            if(count<2)
                board[row][col]='O';
            if(count>3)
                board[row][col]='O';
        }
        else if((row-1>=0) && (col-1<0))
        {
            if(board[row][col+1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row][col]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row+1][col+1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row-1][col]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row+1][col]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row-1][col+1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row+1][col]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row-1][col]=='X')
                count++;
            if(count<2)
                board[row][col]='O';
            if(count>3)
                board[row][col]='O';
        }
        else if((row-1<0) && (col-1<0))
        {
            if(board[row][col+1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row][col]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row+1][col+1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row][col]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row+1][col]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row][col+1]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row+1][col]=='X')
                count++;
            if(board[row][col]=='X')
                count++;
            if(count<2)
                board[row][col]='O';
            if(count>3)
                board[row][col]='O';
        }
    }
}
```

So what I did here is I remade `checkNeighbors` with one huge if statement around the if statements that check for other cells. They now make it so that if `row` or `col` are negative, during the check on neighboring cells it will NOT -1 to whatever it will make negative.

Comment: +1 just because Game Of Life

Comment: You had more code than this in order to generate the output you showed; and I suspect the error is there. Can you show everything needed to reproduce the problem? How are `board` and `check` initialized? And why do you put `row=3, col=3;` in `placeLiveCells`?

Comment: You're not checking for out-of-bounds access in `checkNeighbors`.

Comment: the row=3, col=3 was part of an earlier attempt i made that failed, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: For checking out-of-bounds access, does that involve nesting the if statements in said function in another one?

Comment: Before every occurrence of `[col-1]` you have to add `col > 0 &&`, and likewise for `row`, as well as in every `col+1` the opposite test for the max value.

Comment: There is a easier way if you want to cross the borders to the opposite side, as your latest edit seems to indicate: use a `%` "modulus".

Comment: So basically for the solution I made in my latest edit I need to add a few more `else if` statements? Also, I do not understand how I could use modulus in this, although when I am finished writing  the program I will look into it (for now I just want to finish it the way that I currently understand it lol). Thanks for the tips man :)

Comment: You can have underflow or overflow, and in rows or columns, so that indeed needs 4 checks in total. As you see it leads to rather a lot of code. Try `if (row > 0 && col > 0 && board[row-1][col-1])` instead (and all of its variations). The `mod` trick is, by the way, `board[(2*row-1)%HEIGHT][(2*col-1)%WIDTH]` -- then you can't have overflow.